# Creating a trigger before insert

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to update an entry if already exists using a trigger. I would like to check if an entry exists update if not then insert. When I tried to insert new entry I got an error: 'Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER check_table_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON Songs FOR EACH ROW BEGIN IF NEW.PageURL =(
  SELECT 
    Songs.PageURL 
  FROM 
    Songs 
  WHERE 
    Songs.PageURL = NEW.PageURL
) THEN 
UPDATE 
  Songs 
SET 
  Songs.Title = NEW.Title, 
  Songs.Album = NEW.Album, 
  Songs.Label = NEW.Label, 
  Songs.Release_Date = NEW.Release_Date, 
  Songs.PageURL = NEW.PageURL, 
  Songs.IsSingle = NEW.IsSingle, 
  Songs.Code = NEW.Code, 
  Songs.ImageURL = NEW.ImageURL, 
  Songs.Link_320 = NEW.Link_320, 
  Songs.Link_128 = NEW.Link_128, 
  Songs.Link_48 = NEW.Link_48, 
  Songs.AlbumURL = NEW.AlbumURL 
WHERE 
  Songs.PageURL = NEW.PageURL;
END IF;
END;
// DELIMITER;
```

Comment: There is no way of avoiding this error in a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an appropriate use for a trigger.

If you want to perform a "insert or update" operation on a table, use the [`INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE …`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax. It already has the semantics you are looking for.

If the columns you are updating amount to the entirety of the row, you may be able to use the [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) verb as an alternative to `INSERT`. Note that it will delete the row before insetting a new one, so any columns not included in the `REPLACE` query will be lost.